# Reference parent class of method when `this` seems to been reset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope

I'm using react google charts and am trying to use the `chartEvents` method to hook into [the selection event](https://github.com/RakanNimer/react-google-charts/blob/master/README.md#listen-to-chart-events).

This works:

```
const ChartClass = React.createClass({
  getInitialState () {
    return {
      showModal: false
    }
  },
  handleShowModal () {
    this.setState((prev, props) => {
       return {
         showModal: true
       }
    })
  },
  chartEvents: [
    {
      eventName: 'select',
      callback: function (Chart) {
         this.handleShowModal()
      }
    }
  ],
  render () {
    return (
      <Chart
        chartEvents={this.chartEvents}
        data={this.props.data}
      />
    )
  }
})
```

However within that callback I would like to call some other methods

```
this.handleOpenModal(ChartObj) // TypeError: this.handleOpenModal is not a function
this.sthElse()
```

because within this callback `this` is being set to event itself

```
console.log(this) //object {eventName: "select", callback: function}
```

Is there any way to reference the parent class so I can use its methods? I don't think I can simply place the function outside of the class because it needs to use `this.setState`

Comment: @bergi can you point me to how i can use some of that in my react class please

Comment: You haven't really shown enough of the class code for that, no.

Comment: @Bergi Updated. Can you take a look please

Comment: You will need to put the creation of the `chartEvents` in the constructor, where they can be initialised as instance-specific. All the approaches in the duplicate post to bind `this` will work in the constructor scope.

Comment: @Bergi I don't believe `React.createClass` has a constructor like `React.Component`...

Comment: Looks like you get to put it inside `getInitialState` then. You can also do it inside `render`, but afaik that's discouraged

Comment: @Bergi defining a parameter within `getInitialState` will also make it available only via `this`. And yes, putting it in `render` is def unideal. I believe that closing this question within a few minutes of it being asked was a hasty and unfortunate decision. Are you still certain about it?

Comment: That should work, in `render` you can access it via `this`. But yeah, react is a bit of a special thing, I'll reopen and answer

Answer (score 0):

`React.createClass` components did auto-bind all their methods, so you need to do nothing but declare the callback as a method - or just use `handleShowModal` directly:

```
const ChartClass = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      showModal: false
    }
  },
  handleShowModal(Chart) {
    this.setState((prev, props) => {
      return {
        showModal: true
      }
    })
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <Chart
        chartEvents={[
          {
            eventName: 'select',
            callback: this.handleShowModal
          }
        ]}
        data={this.props.data}
      />
    )
  }
})
```

Of course, given you are using ES6 anyway, you probably should just switch to `class` syntax.

---

A (probably considered hacky) alternative would be to create the `chartEvents` with the [bound callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback?noredirect=1&lq=1) in the `getInitialState` method:

```
const ChartClass = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    this.chartEvents = [
      {
        eventName: 'select',
        callback: (Chart) => { // use arrow functions
          this.handleShowModal()
        } // or .bind(this) or whatever here
      }
    ];
    return {
      showModal: false
    }
  },
  handleShowModal () {
    this.setState((prev, props) => {
       return {
         showModal: true
       }
    })
  },
  render () {
    return (
      <Chart
        chartEvents={this.chartEvents}
        data={this.props.data}
      />
    )
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to bind "this" in the callback

This can be done by

Using an arrow function

```
   chartEvents: [
     {
       eventName: 'select',
       callback:  Chart => {
         console.log('component', Chart.chart.getSelection()) //yep, shows the selection
       }
     }
   ],
```

Binding

```
   chartEvents: [
     {
       eventName: 'select',
       callback: function (Chart) {
         console.log('component', Chart.chart.getSelection()) //yep, shows the selection
       }.bind(this)
     }
   ],
```

Comment: Both of these produce the same error unfortunately.